# how to show image coming from file input on angular with PHP backend

Tags: php, angular, file

I need to show in a blog the image of the post but I can't show it in the post

my angular method for getPost:

```
  async getNotices(): Promise<void> {
    this.opnSpinner();
    const response = await this.BlogService.getNotices();
    if (response['result'].length > 0) {
      const notices: object[] = [];
      for (const item of response['result']) {
        const notice = {};
        notice['id'] = item['ID_NOTICIA'];
        notice['title'] = item['TITLE'];
        notice['subTitle'] = item['SUBTITLE'];
        notice['content'] = item['CONTENT'];
        notice['img'] =  item['IMG'];
        notice['date'] = item['DATA_FORMATADA'];
        notices.push(notice);
        console.log(notice);
      }
```

i using angular fileUploader to get the image comes like this: img: "C:fakepathIMAGEMTESTE.jpg"

my PHP method:

```
function addPost() {
    global $mysql;

    $result = new stdClass();
    $result->status = true;
    $result->msg = '';
    $sql = '';
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body = json_decode($request->getBody());

    $title = $body->title;
    $subTitle = $body->subTitle;
    $content = $body->content;
    $img = $body->img;

    
    $mysql->beginTransaction(); 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO BLOG (TITLE, SUBTITLE,CONTENT, IMG ) VALUES ('${title}', '${subTitle}', '${content}', '${img}')";

    $result->status = $mysql->execute($sql);

    if($result->status === false) {
        $result->msg = 'Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar o post';
        $mysql->rollBack();
    }else {
        $result->msg = 'Post cadastrado com sucesso';
        $mysql->commit();
    }
    echo '{ "result" : ' . json_encode($result) . ' }';
}
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: If you get `C:fakepathIMAGEMTESTE.jpg` in PHP, then you're not actually uploading the file, you're just sending the fake path the browser uses. You need to do some research how to upload files using angular and then how to handle uploads in PHP.

Comment: how can i improve this?

Comment: You start by using google, search for what you're trying to do (one thing at the time, something like "how to upload file using angular" and "how to handle uploads in php".) When you've read some tutorials, you make some attempts. If you then get stuck on something specific along the way, you can come back and ask about that.

Comment: ok i will try thanks!